# bootstrap tree view plugin convert in codigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, plugins, treeview

I want to convert Bootstrap Treeview plugin into CodeIgniter, it runs normally on core PHP but when I convert it into CodeIgniter, it shows only array result.

Result: [My code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNH4u.jpg)

Source: [Bootstrap Treeview source](http://www.webslesson.info/2017/05/make-treeview-using-bootstrap-treeview-ajax-jquery-with-php.html) I want to convert it into CodeIgniter

`fetch.php` - controller

```
<?php

class Fetch extends MY_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->view('dashboard');
        // $query (= " SELECT * FROM country_state_city ";
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM country_state_city ");
        // (" SELECT * FROM country_state_city ")->result_array() ;

        //$output = array();
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $sub_data["id"] = $row["id"];
            $sub_data["name"] = $row["name"];
            $sub_data["text"] = $row["name"];
            $sub_data["parent_id"] = $row["parent_id"];
            $data[] = $sub_data;

        }


        foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
            $output[$value["id"]] = &$value;
        }

        foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
            if ($value["parent_id"] && isset($output[$value["parent_id"]])) {
                $output[$value["parent_id"]]["nodes"][] = &$value;
            }
        }

        foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
            if ($value["parent_id"] && isset($output[$value["parent_id"]])) {
                unset($data[$key]);
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($data);

    }
}

?>
```

## dashboard.php - view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ajax jaquey tree grid</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.css"/>

    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<br/><br/>
<div class="container" style="width:500px;">
    <h2 align="center">Make Treeview using Bootstrap Treeview Ajax JQuery with PHP</h2>
    <br/><br/>
    <div id="treeview"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>fetch",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#treeview').treeview({data: data});
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: why do you paste `<script>` after closing `HTML` tag as the example? I didn't see any differences between example code and yours. Can you share, inspect element, or source code of output?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load data using ajax request then no need to load it in index() function.

You have to load the only view in an index() and make another function for tree view like this:

You load all data on page load then also make ajax call which is not correct.

**Controller:**

```
<?php

class Test_c extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->view('test');


    }
    function tree() {
        // $query (= " SELECT * FROM country_state_city ";
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM country_state_city ");
        // (" SELECT * FROM country_state_city ")->result_array() ;

        //$output = array();
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $sub_data["id"] = $row["id"];
            $sub_data["name"] = $row["name"];
            $sub_data["text"] = $row["name"];
            $sub_data["parent_id"] = $row["parent_id"];
            $data[] = $sub_data;

        }


        foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
            $output[$value["id"]] = &$value;
        }

        foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
            if ($value["parent_id"] && isset($output[$value["parent_id"]])) {
                $output[$value["parent_id"]]["nodes"][] = &$value;
            }
        }

        foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
            if ($value["parent_id"] && isset($output[$value["parent_id"]])) {
                unset($data[$key]);
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}

?>
```

Try like this. It works.
Rest of things is correct.

Hope you solve your error using my solution.

Greetings....